# Using DeckGL with Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I am struggling to get Deck play nice with vue. all the examples I have found till today are either quite hacked, not really my use case or out of date.

Does anyone know a good first step Source I could look at to get started?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you ever found your solution or if you found other content, but I just wanted to post some info here in case you or anyone else who finds there way here needs some help on this.

There is a open source library we are working on to help bootstrap DeckGL/Mapbox implementations in Vue while providing some and soon more helpful abstractions.

Here is a couple links you may find useful:

- Repo: https://github.com/loftylabs/vue_deckgl
- Tutorial and documentation: https://loftylabs.github.io/vue_deckgl/

Feel free to stop by the repo and drop questions in issues if you are looking for any more help!